# Php Sql Search multiple tables with keyword and display search results

Tags: php, sql

Pretty much I want to be able to search with a keyword in multiple tables then display the matching results from each of the tables (products, services, blog posts). I have code that works to search in one table and have fiddled a little bit with UNION in the query but not sure where to go from here. I'm not very experienced in php. If anyone could show me example of how its used with my code would really help

```
<?php
include "config.php";
include 'Header.php';

// declares two arrays
$results = array();
$errors = array();

// get search textbox
$searchTerms = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_GET['search']);

// check if the length is not less than 2 chars
if (strlen($searchTerms) < 3) {
   $errors[] = "Your search term must be longer than 2 characters";
}  

// if there is no error, let perform the search
if (count($errors) < 1) {

  $query = "(SELECT * FROM tbl_products WHERE product_name LIKE '%{$searchTerms}%' OR product_description LIKE '%{$searchTerms}%')
   UNION
   (SELECT * FROM tbl_blog WHERE blog_title LIKE '%{$searchTerms}%' OR blog_content LIKE '%{$searchTerms}%') 
   UNION
   (SELECT * FROM service_categories WHERE serviceCat_name LIKE '%{$searchTerms}%')";          
   $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

   //checks if the search yields any result
   if (mysqli_num_rows($result) < 1) {
     $errors[] = "Your search term yielded no results!<hr>";
   }
   else {
     //loop and store through all the results 
     while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
       extract($row);
       $results[] = '<a class="searchPageBox" href="viewProperty.php?propertyID='.$product_ID.'"><div style="width: 100%;"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-4">'.'<img style="width:100%; height=100%;" src="product-images/'.$product_image.'"  /></div><div class="col-md-8"><h3 class="searchPageTitle">'.$product_name.'</h3><div class="searchPageDesc">'.$product_description.'</div></div></div></div></a><hr>';
     } // end of while

   } // end of else

} // end of if

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Search Site</title>
</head>

<body class="homepage">
<div id="page">
    <div id="two-column1" class="container">
        <div id="colB">
            <h3 class="searchPropertiesHeading">SEARCH PROPERTIES</h3>
        </div>
        <div id="colA">
            <!-- PHP here -->
            <h2 class="searchResults">Search Results for
            <span style="font-weight: bold"><?php echo $searchTerms ?></span>:</h2>
            <div>
                <?php echo count($results) ?>results</div>
            <hr><?php
          // display the search results here
          if (count($results) >0) {
              echo "".implode("", $results);
          }

          // display the error here
          if (count($errors) >0) {
              echo "".implode("<br>", $errors);
          }

         ?></div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php 
include 'Footer.php'; 
?>
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `UNION ALL` is a solution. But it requires that all subqueries return the same number of columns, having the same datatype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who wants to know how the resulting query ended up:

```
$query = "(SELECT 'product' AS type, 'product' AS link, product_ID AS ID, product_name AS name, product_description AS description, product_image AS image FROM tbl_products WHERE product_name LIKE '%{$searchTerms}%' OR product_description LIKE '%{$searchTerms}%')
   UNION
   (SELECT 'blog' AS type, 'blog' AS link, blog_ID AS ID, blog_title AS name, blog_content AS description, blog_image AS image FROM tbl_blog WHERE blog_title LIKE '%{$searchTerms}%' OR blog_content LIKE '%{$searchTerms}%') 
   UNION
   (SELECT 'service' AS type, 'serviceCat' AS link, serviceCat_ID AS ID, serviceCat_name AS name, serviceCat_description AS description, serviceCat_image AS image FROM service_categories WHERE serviceCat_name LIKE '%{$searchTerms}%' OR serviceCat_description LIKE '%{$searchTerms}%') ORDER BY name ASC";     
   $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);


   if (mysqli_num_rows($result) < 1) {
     $errors[] = "Your search term yielded no results!<hr>";
   }
   else {
     //loop and store through all the results 
     while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
       extract($row);
       $results[] = '<a class="searchPageBox" href="view'.$type.'.php?'.$link.'ID='.$ID.'"><div style="width: 100%;"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-4">'.'<img style="width:100%; height=100%;" src="product-images/'.$image.'"  /></div><div class="col-md-8"><h3 class="searchPageTitle">'.$name.'</h3><div class="searchPageDesc">'.$description.'</div></div></div></div></a><hr>';
} 


     // end of while

   } // end of else

} // end of if
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to display all the results in the same "table" (for example HTML table, but doesn't matter what type of visualisation is used), you need to define a fixed number of column for each table.

For example, if you have product (id, name, price, description, category) and blog (id, title, body), you can have a union of both using 3 columns (id, type and result).

- ID: Unique identifier for each type.
- TYPE: "blog", "product", etc, probably something that you can generate a link to the item.
- RESULT: Text where is show why this row was selected. You can concatenate multiple fields with `||`.

Example:

```
$query = "(SELECT id, 'product', product_name || ' ' || product_description FROM tbl_products WHERE product_name LIKE '%{$searchTerms}%' OR product_description LIKE '%{$searchTerms}%')
   UNION
   (SELECT id, 'blog', blog_title || ' ' || blog_content  FROM tbl_blog WHERE blog_title LIKE '%{$searchTerms}%' OR blog_content LIKE '%{$searchTerms}%') 
   UNION
   (SELECT id, 'services', serviceCat_name  FROM service_categories WHERE serviceCat_name LIKE '%{$searchTerms}%')";
```

Comment: Ok thanks. Im pretty clueless on how to do it. Is there any chance someone can provide an example using my code?

Comment: I've added an example.

Comment: As a normal table, by the column name. You can set a column name using `AS`. For example `column1 || column2 AS new_column`.

Comment: I have gotten it to work and display the results, thanks for the help. However I need to some how make the link displayed change so that the result can be clicked to take the user to the corresponding page. Any ideas?